# group_concat_max_len value gets changed to default on restart

Tags: mysql, centos

I am changing the value of group_concat_max_len to 15000 using

```
SET  group_concat_max_len=15000;
```

I achieve what I what but when I restart mysql server, it is set to default 1024.

How can I make it static to 15000, I assume, I should be able to set this value in mysql config file. I added `group_concat_max_len=15000` in my.cnf and restarted the server. The value remained same i.e 1024.

Can I set it in a way so that the value remains same when mysql server is restarted?

Comment: see this https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/508756-MySQL-problem-configuring-group_concat_max_len-in-my-cnf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to put it in the config file :

**LINUX:** `my.cnf` file

**WINDOWS:** `my.ini` file

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=15000
```

**Note:** Add this line `group_concat_max_len=15000` under `mysqld` section. You need to restart your `MySQL` server to see the effect.

Comment: Tried that but I didn't add [mysql], let me try that